# Django can not connect to MySQL database

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-10.04

I am newbie in Django.

I got a simple Django 1.3.* project, i would like to run it over my localhost. 
I installed all necessary modules like: python-mysqldb, rptz etc...
I have ubuntu 10.04 installed with python 2.7.2.
When i tried to start project in terminal

```
thor@thor:/media/SAJAT - Projects/project/simple project$ python manage.py runserver
```

I got the following error message:

```
> Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1224910>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 102, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 338, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.30.101' (110)")
```

I have no idea where this IP address comes from 172.17.30.101' (110)  because of my mysql server has been installed on my computer(localhost)

Here is my settings.py file

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'dbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': 'dbuser',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '123456',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
 #'PORT': '3306', i tried with this too                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
 #'PORT': '3360', i tried with this too                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        },
        # 'read': {
        #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        #     'NAME': 'newsonia',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        #     'USER': 'dbuser',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        #     'PASSWORD': 'dbname',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        #     'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        #     'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        # }
    }
```

I have no idea how should be resolve this kind of errors.

Comment: Try different ip and port, Let's see what error will come `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`

Comment: Unfortonetly i got exatly same error.:( _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.30.101' (110)")

Comment: have you tried leaving it blank (since the default is localhost) also make sure mysqld is running.

Comment: Yes of course i tried it too, and mysql server is also running,thor@thor:/$ pgrep -l mysqld
19842 mysqld

Comment: An interesting thing i just comment all lines in my settings.py and i got the same error. I really have no idea what's going on. :)

Comment: Is there something altered in djangos global_settings.py?

Comment: Are you sure that settings file is being called?

Comment: Can you just check your `manage.py` and check your env. for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` ?

Comment: Finally i got the problem, the project used another settings file. :) Thank you everyone for your answers